Migration assistant without quitting apps
I need to setup another macbook as quickly as possible, so I'm planning to use Migration Assistant with thunderbolt 4, which should take about 30 minutes from what I've heard. However, I cannot close apps on my old macbook for certain reasons. Is there a way to force Migration Assistant to run without closing other apps?

To copy all user files, Migration assistant needs admin (root) permissions, so it can call the launctctl reboot user space type routines and other tasks that you’ll have a hard time interrupting.
If you can set up Time Machine you could migrate from a just completed backup interval to an ejectable media  rather than your running system, but I can’t see anyone spending a lot of time reverse engineering this tool to hijack it and allow apps to keep writing user data while migration assistant is trying to copy it over to a new machine.
